# Rails - how to add an attribute to a text_field_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, textfield, custom-data-attribute

I want to add a data attribute to a text field tag

```
<%= text_field_tag(:address) %>
```

which produces

```
<input id="address" type="text" name="address") %>
```

to make it have the HTML of

```
<input id="address" type="text" name="address" data-clob="ccc") %>
```

so I tried

```
<%= text_field_tag(:address, data:{clob: 'ccc'}) %>
```

but it was added as the actual value instead of an attribute, i.e.

```
<input id="address" type="text" value="{:data=>{:clob=>"ccc"}}" name="address"></input>
```

even though for a text field label I had used

```
<%= label_tag(:address, t("ui.reservations.between_now_and_param", 
param: @start_date.strftime(    time_format)), data:{blob: 'bbb'})%>
```

as detailed in [How to add HTML5 data- attributes to a rails form label tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803507/how-to-add-html5-data-attributes-to-a-rails-form-label-tag)

How can I add it as an attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was that a second parameter was required for the value and using `""` or `,,` didn't work but but using `nil` did - caused no "value=" attribute to be generated, e.g.

```
<%= text_field_tag(:address, nil, data:{clob: 'ccc'}) %>
```

Though I need to see if that works if this form is redisplayed on error...